# Synchronization of two RTMP streams with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I have the problem right now that I need to merge two or more streams into one, the problem is that they are out of sync.

Is there any way to calculate or compare Stream 1 with Stream 2 and get the desync times and `desync` them automatically with ffmpeg?

I know there is an option `-itsoffset`, but for that I have to set the delay manually for each stream, which would be a lot of hassle.